# How to solve simultaneous inequalities (reasked)?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

I am doing multivariable calculus, and specifically double integrals. I am facing difficulties finding the domain of the integal, however i am given the following equations:
$$1≤2x+y≤2$$
$$0≤x−2y≤1$$
Through these two equations i am supposed to find the area of integrals for each of the variables i.e $x$ and $y$
I set them as simultaneous inequalities but it doesn't seem to help because i get the boundary for xx to be $$2/5≤x≤1$$ and for $y$ to be $$4/5≤y≤0$$  which is obviously **WRONG** because how can the lowest boundary for the integral possibly have higher value than that in the higher.

[Here is where i have posted my question originally](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791371/how-to-solve-simultaneous-inequalities?newreg=1a40bc9c64704affb27e6c0f52053af6%20%22It%20is%20a%20definite%20copy%20if%20this%20quetion)
please don't get me wrong, I am thankful to all the lovely & helpful people who tried to help (Henning Makholm, Shardulc, AlphaGo) and for the up-voting, its just i was new to this community and i thought they wanted my email to spam me, so i logged in as a guest.

Anyways, i just don't get how all these people arrived at their solution, is there a known way to solve such problems?
Thank you all for everything.

Comment: Trying to read the solutions given in your other post is advisable. The answers given are good. You'll have to back up quite a bit of you don't understand them. Can you do a double integral over a basic rectangle in $xy$ e.g. $0<x<1$ and $2<y<4$?

Comment: @Did thanks for the informative comment but i do believe that i have put the link to the original question and given a reason why i am reasking the question. :)

Comment: @jdods they are in fact the answers that the examiner has given us in the key but they problem here i dont know how its been done i mean the way of thinking that lead to the solution thats why i am asking you guys to refer me to the known ways of solving such problems i mean if there is a name for a known method that i could google! thank you for your time :)

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TQiPN.jpg  This image may make things clearer. you are trying to integrate over the awkward quadrilateral, which is why one answer suggested changing variables and the other split the range for $x$ into three parts. Bother, not tried that before, I thought it would display image, but it only displays the link! You need to click it.

Comment: There isn't a name for the method as far as I know. Is just doing a double integral in rectangular coordinates where you have to split up the region of integration. The other method that Henning Malcolm showed you is called change of variables or coordinate transformation.

Comment: @Leo Your rationalization to repost this does not hold water since you are deliberately posting this although you know it is a duplicate and you know that duplicates are an explicit no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2x + y \ge 1$ is area above a line.
$2x + y \le 2$ is the area below a parallel line.  Put them together and you have a ribbon between two parallel lines.

And with the other equation also forms a ribbon that follows a different line.  The two ribbons intersect to form a parallelogram.

If you "solve" the system of equations you will need to solve

$2x + y = 1\\
x - 2y = 0$

and

$2x + y = 2\\
x - 2y = 0$

etc.  4 pairs of equations to find 4 vertexes.

But if your goal is to do a double integration, what you really want it to say

$x = 2u + v\\
y = u - 2v\\
1\le 5u \le 2\\
0\le 5v \le 1$

$dy\,dx = || (\frac {dx}{du},\frac {dy}{du})\times(\frac {dx}{dv},\frac {dy}{dv})|| du\,dv = 5 \,du\,dv $

$\int_0^{\frac15}\int_{\frac15}^{\frac25} f(u,v) 5 \,du \,dv$

Comment: Thank you alot for such an informative answer. the process of u-v-subitiution what is it called? because it involves the cross product which is why i need a name for the method to google! please if you know any name, website, video that has to do with this, do refer me to it. I am grateful for your help

Comment: It is called a change of variables, or a transformation.  It is the multivariate equivalent of a u-substitution in single variable calculus.  The cross product is the "Jacobian" of the transformation.  http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant